# How do I progress with cracking this monoalphabetic substitution cipher that ignores natural word divisions?

Tags: decryption, substitution-cipher

Having some trouble cracking this cipher (this is part of a homework assignment for a cryptology class) I've looked at letter frequencies but I'm not sure what else there is to help me.

Given the encrypted string, `TNFOS FOZSW PZLOC GQAOZ WAGQR PJZPN ABCZP QDOGR AMTHA RAXTB AGZJO GMTHA RAVAP ZW`, the word `LIBERTY` is encrypted somewhere in the ciphertext.

From that, I find A and Z line up almost perfectly to E and T given a frequency chart and based off of that, I can pinpoint possible locations of the word LIBERTY (blue text). But after that, I don't really see anything to do to further decrypt it. With no spacing I cant really make out any words
[image: problem attempt]

Comment: Hints: How many _positions_ of `LIBERTY` relative to the start of the plaintext are possible for a 67-character plaintext? Can you exclude some of these given the particular ciphertext and knowing it's monoalphabetic substitution)? Would your eye+brain be enough to find the plaintext among what remains, if you wrote a program that displays the candidate plaintexts with `.` for characters where there's a remaining ambiguity? For short plaintext that approach has lower probability to miis than pure frequency distribution.

Comment: HInt: you might like to think of famous quotes involving the word "liberty"and compare them to the two possibilities.

Comment: Also: after a guess of the position of liberty, it's likely that S stands for one of the characters among the most frequent that remain. A program could also show that guess.